# Comment traduire la réponse sarcastique « NOT! »

Tags: expressions, langage-informel

Comment est-ce qu’on traduirait « NOT! » comme réponse de plaisanterie ?

*« You’re really good at drawing... NOT! »*

Ça veut dire qu’on mentait, qu’on voulait être méchant et c’est très sarcastique.

Sur wordreference il y a *« ou pas ».*

*« Comme tu assures en dessiner... ou pas ! »*

Ça serait un bon équivalent ou pas trop ?

Comment: *Comme tu assures en **dessin** !*

Comment: oups, merci ! t’as raison 

Answer (score 1):

"Ou pas" placé à la fin après des points de suspension (… ou pas) fonctionnerait parfaitement.

Comment: Pas tant que ça, ***ou pas*** laisse la question (un peu) ouverte alors que ***not*** y met définitivement fin.

Comment: Exemple : "Heureusement que t'étais là... Ou pas." Je trouve aussi que cela fonctionne parfaitement. Cette locution ne laisse point d'ouverture, et est tout aussi sarcastique que le "...NOT".